# Beamer page scaling

Tags: beamer, paper-size

I would like to make Beamer slides compile to an A4 page size.

```tex
\documentclass[aspectratio=141]{beamer}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage{pgfpages}
%\pgfpagesuselayout{resize to}[a4paper,landscape]

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Hello World}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:nonnegative}
    (a - b)^2 \ge 0
\end{equation}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Hello World}
Look at \eqref{eq:nonnegative}.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Currently pdfLaTeX produces a PDF which is 148.5mm by 105mm (A6). Is it possible to scale the entire document so that it is A4 size? This is [possible](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10244/81373) using `pgfpages`; however this destroys hyperlinks, so I was looking for alternatives.

Comment: `pgfpages` doesn't actually destroy the links, it just doesn't scale them with the rest of the page or otherwise positions them incorrectly. You should be able to see the badly positioned link boxes if you use `\hypersetup{hidelinks=false, pdfborder={1 1 1}}`. That's not very important, though since it's solved by using `\geometry`. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `\geometry{mag=2000,truedimen}` after declaring `beamer` as the document class (see [`geometry` documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/geometry) for explanation). This works with the MWE; I've yet to see if it breaks anything.