# Beamer really change paper size, and paperheight

Tags: beamer, geometry

I'd like to change the beamer paper size, but the problem is that when I change it the frame of the main document goes out of the page, and has therefore a unusable paperheight. And because I'd like to use the paperheight to position my elements precisely, it's quite annoying...

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\geometry{showframe,paperwidth=297mm,paperheight=210mm,margin=5mm,nohead,nofoot,nomarginpar}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]{}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{}

\begin{document}
This frame goes out of this document.
\end{document}
```

The top part is ok:

[image: top port]

but not the bottom part:

[image: bottom part]

Thank you !

Comment: Which is another reason I use pdfscreen and texpower instead of beamer.

Comment: maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/397395/beamer-page-scaling/397415#397415 could help

Answer (score 5):

As the documentation says

> you should refrain from changing the “paper size.”

You should take this warning seriously. beamer does  a lot of manual calculations and settings and so changing the layout after the class can not be done with a simple `\geometry` call.

Use the `141` aspectratio instead. It leads to a 148.5mm by 105mm page size, which is exactly the half of your values.